# Cache Django view until table in database is updated

Tags: django, django-views

So far I have easy solution:

```
@cache_page(60 * 60 * 24)
def myview()
```

Which works fine. What bothers me though, that what if table in database changes (someone uploades data), then cached view should be re-evaluated. Moreover, since I rarely and irregularly have DB updates, I would like to **not** specify the 60 * 60 * 24 (once a day), but be it infinity unless DB's table changes (or maybe entire DB changes).

What do I do? I'm sure there is easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it works. In order to invalidate the cache you could use a signal to clear certain cache entry when certain model instance is saved.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/

As for setting an infinite cache, use `None` as timeout and it will never expire (Django 1.7+).